# Do any post-RigVedic deities appear in the principal upanishads?

Tags: upanishads, vedic-gods

I am taking

```
Brhadaranyaka Upanishad
Chandogya Upanishad
Taittiriya Upanishad
Aitereya Upanishad
Kausitaki Upanishad
Kena Upanishad
Katha Upanishad
Isha Upanishad
Svetasvatara Upanishad
Mundaka Upanishad
Prashna Upanishad
Maitri Upanishad
Mandukya Upanishad
```

as principal upanishads.

Are any post-RigVedic deities mentioned in these Upanishads?

By RigVedic, I primarily mean (along with verses dedicated to them)

Indra 250
Agni 200
Soma 123
Aśvins 56
Varuna 46
Maruts 38
Mitra 28[3]
Ushas 21
Vayu (Wind) 12
Savitr 11
the Rbhus 11
Pushan 10
the Apris 9
Brhaspati 8
Surya (Sun) 8
Dyáuṣ Pitṛ́ and Pṛthvī Mātṛ́ (Heaven and Earth) 6, plus 5.84 dedicated to Earth alone
Apas (Waters) 6
Adityas 6
Vishnu 6
Brahmanaspati 6
Rudra 5

Comment: Can you clarify in the question what you mean by post-Rigvedic dieties? Perhaps provide a list of Rigvedic dieties?

Comment: @hashable kali, Ganesha, Kartika(son of lord Shiva) and maa Durga(apparently)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma Haimavati appears in the [Kena upanishad](http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/upanishads/kena_upanishad.php). She points out to Indra that the yaksha they have seen is brahman and the deva-s won their victory due to brahman.

> अथेन्द्रमब्रुवन्मघवन्नेतद्विजानीहि किमेतद्यक्षमिति तथेति
> तदभ्यद्रवत्तस्मात्तिरोदधे ॥ 3.11॥

> स तस्मिन्नेवाकाशे स्त्रियमाजगाम बहुशोभमाना**मुमाँ
> हैमवतीं** ताँहोवाच किमेतद्यक्षमिति ॥ 3.12 ॥

> सा ब्रह्मेति होवाच ब्रह्मणो वा एतद्विजये महीयध्वमिति
> ततो हैव विदाञ्चकार ब्रह्मेति ॥ 4.1॥

> Then the gods said to Indra: "O Maghavan! Find out who this great Spirit is." "Yes," he said and hastened to It. But the Spirit disappeared from him. Then Indra beheld in that very region of the sky a Woman highly adorned. **She was Uma, the daughter of the Himalayas.** He approached Her and said: "Who is this great Spirit?"

> Chapter IV

> She replied: "It is, indeed, Brahman. Through the victory of Brahman alone have you attained glory." After that Indra understood that It was Brahman.

Comment: Great find, @alsoran